# Django tagging and django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-tagging

How can I add something like a dropdown list or text input with the tags as a search in django admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   class YourModel(models.Model):
       ...
       tags = TagField()
```

But if you register your model, you'll have to choose a different `tag_descriptor_attr`.

Checkout the [overview](https://github.com/brosner/django-tagging/blob/master/docs/overview.txt) file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer e-satis; I don't quite following the documentation, do you have an example of how to choose a different `tag_descriptor_attr`?

Comment: To answer myself it is simply: `tagregister(MyModel, tag_descriptor_attr='tag_list')`